# Dplyr group_by and arrange functions together doesn't group same values together

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the mtcars built-in dataset. My code is as following:

```
data("mtcars")
a <- mtcars %>%
       group_by(cyl) %>%
       arrange(hp)
```

The output that I get:

> ```
>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
>  1  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
>  2  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
>  3  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1
>  4  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1
>  5  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1
>  6  26       4 120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
>  7  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
>  8  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
>  9  21.5     4 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1
> 10  18.1     6 225     105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
> 11  21.4     4 121     109  4.11  2.78  18.6     1     1     4     2
> 12  21       6 160     110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
> 13  21       6 160     110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
> 14  21.4     6 258     110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
> 15  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     5     2
> 16  19.2     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
> 17  17.8     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
> 18  15.5     8 318     150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     3     2
> 19  15.2     8 304     150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     3     2
> 20  18.7     8 360     175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
> 21  19.2     8 400     175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     3     2
> 22  19.7     6 145     175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6
> 23  16.4     8 276.    180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
> 24  17.3     8 276.    180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
> 25  15.2     8 276.    180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
> 26  10.4     8 472     205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
> 27  10.4     8 460     215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
> 28  14.7     8 440     230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4
> 29  14.3     8 360     245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
> 30  13.3     8 350     245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4
> 31  15.8     8 351     264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4
> 32  15       8 301     335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
> ```

As you can see group_by is redundant in this output. I only get my data arranged by "hp" column. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I want to see everything grouped by "cyl" column and then arranged by "hp".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping isn't really related to sorting. Also, `group_by` isn't redundant (in the sense of being absolutely ignored) as the second line of the output is

```
# Groups:   cyl [3]
```

To see that `group_by` doesn't do sorting, just try

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% print(n = Inf)
```

Hence, what you want is first to arrange by `cyl` and then by `hp`:

```
mtcars %>% arrange(cyl, hp)
```